ubuntu subiquity_log.3595[12792]: finish: cmd-in-target: FAIL: curtin command in-target | Installation Failure
I am experiencing significant difficulties while attempting to install ZFS Encrypted Ubuntu on my External SSD. Below are some relevant log entries that highlight the issue:
codes [0] (capture=False)
Oct 12 01:25:40 ubuntu subiquity_log.3595[12792]: Running command ['umount', '/target/dev'] with allowed return codes [0] (capture=False)
Oct 12 01:25:40 ubuntu subiquity_log.3595[12792]: finish: cmd-in-target: FAIL: curtin command in-target
Oct 12 01:25:40 ubuntu subiquity_event.3595[3595]:  configuring keyboard
Oct 12 01:25:40 ubuntu subiquity_event.3595[3595]: installing system
Oct 12 01:25:40 ubuntu subiquity_event.3595[3595]: 
Oct 12 01:25:40 ubuntu subiquity_event.3595[3595]:   curtin command in-target

I greatly appreciate any support you can provide. I have already tried rebooting the system, but the issue persists.
Ubuntu "Something went wrong" error message:

Full log accessible here: https://pastebin.com/uiKbkCAM
